# QT switching QSystemTrayIcon at runtime

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to switch the `QSystemTrayIcon` at runtime. But sometimes the app just randomly crashes.

In my mainwindow.h:

```
QSystemTrayIcon *sti = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
```

In my mainwindow.cpp:

```
// In my online method:
QIcon xmediaIcon("://online.png");
sti->setIcon(xmediaIcon);

// In my offline method:
QIcon xmediaIcon("://offline.png");
sti->setIcon(xmediaIcon);
```

Am I doing something wrong? the app launches but crashes after sometime just randomly. Im not sure if I somehow can init the 2 `xmediaIcon` inside the header?

Comment: Any stack trace available?

Answer (score 0):

QSystemTrayIcon::setIcon uses a reference of the object, the object since it's declared in a method will go out of scope as soon as the method ends. I don't know if Qt makes a copy of the icon internally, otherwise it might be the reason of the crash.
Define the icons in a resource file (that is, usually, the best practice) and use them from there.